# Bottom watering for a baby avocado plant?

Tags: watering, avocado

Can I use bottom watering for my avocado plant, instead of watering from the top. I thought that it would be easier to maintain. I would just have to monitor the level of water in the bottom of the pot.

Comment: Do you have the bottom sitting in water all the time?  If so, don't.  You can let them soak up water for 10-15 mins. then dump out the water.

Answer (score 1):

Avacados will eventually die if the tap root at the bottom is always wet.  That doesn't mean what you want to do will kill your avacado tree, it's just that it sounds like a bad idea and a risk.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom watering plants keeps the roots uniformly moist, but it doesn't wash away the salt and mineral deposits that accumulate on the top of the soil over time. 
Pour water over the top of the soil until it drains out the bottom once a month, just to rinse the soil and remove the excess minerals.